# How to echo OS X bash alias' command to terminal after calling it (like !cmd)?

Tags: macos, shell, alias, bash

In ~/.bash_profile aliases are defined, eg. `alias vaguppro='vagrant up --provision`

What I want is an echo of `vagrant up --provision` after typing `vaguppro` in the terminal.

Similar to when one types `ls -hal` in the terminal, then again type `!ls`. There's an echo of `ls -hal` in the terminal before execution.

SOME SOLUTIONS

```
vaguppro='vagrant up --provision'
alias vaguppro='echo $vaguppro && $vaguppro'
```

or andlrc's function solution below.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this shortcut useful:

```
   shell-expand-line (M-C-e)
          Expand the line as the shell does.  This performs alias and his‐
          tory expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions.  See
          HISTORY EXPANSION below for a description of history expansion.
```

In other words, if you write `vaguppro` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in bash' default Emacs mode, it will expand aliases in the current line and turn it into `vagrant up --provision`. You can then press enter to run as usual.

Comment: This is a nice feature, but I never understood why `Alt` is used for mapping in combination with `Ctrl` instead of `Ctrl-Shift`? I personally use `Alt` for system shortcuts, so I miss out of half of these unless I remap them myself.

Comment: ASCII reasons: Shift only works in conjunction with keys that have a defined shifted value, such as `[`->`{` or `e`->`E`. Ctrl only works in conjunction with the 32 ascii chars from 64 to 96, subtracting 64 from their value to produce a control code. Therefore, you can't differentiate between Ctrl+E and Ctrl+Shift+E. Alt, meanwhile, just prepends an Esc character and therefore works with everything. You should get a keyboard with a Windows key (or [Tux key](http://lizquilty.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/tux_keyboard_closeup_800.jpg)), they're the perfect system shortcut key.

Comment: Thanks for a very good breakdown! There is only one Windows key and I'm mostly using left hand, so that causes problems. On ANSI-keyboard you have two Alt keys, on either side of the space bar :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the two Alts (and even Shifts) can be mapped separately, potentially reserving one for shortcuts. CapsLock can also be put to better use.

Answer (score 2):

`!ls` is a history expansion that searches your command history for `ls` and expands to the found command. As a bonus the expansion is also printed to the terminal.

To get the same behavior with your aliases, I think you would need to convert it to a function and print it manually:

```
vaguppro() {
  echo "vagrant up --provision"
  vagrant up --provision "$@"
}
```

I almost always recommend people using functions over aliases, unless it for adding colors for `grep`, `ls`, ...

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias cd..='cd ..'
```

Comment: Might want `vagrant up --provision "$@"`, to be equivalent to the behavior of the alias wrt. passing additional arguments through.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, thanks for noticing, updated answer :)

Comment: @andlrc Why do you recommend functions over aliases?

Comment: @DirkBruins There is a good discussion  over at UnixSE about it: [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function). But in general when it gets more complicated then settings default flags I would prefer a function.