# Print bash command on Alias use

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, bash

I've been setting up lots of aliases lately, it saves me some typing but I'm afraid this might make me forget the original command.
Is there a way to use an alias and at the same time print the original command.
On this alias for example, what would that look like?

```
alias showhidden='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES'
```

- Jor

Comment: If you are talking about **Bash**, you could use the `type` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, this seems overly simplistic, but how about:

```
$alias showhidden='echo defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES;defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES'
```

or a simpler example I just tried:

```
$alias lsl='echo ls -l;ls -l'
$lsl
ls -l
total 120
-rw-r--r--  1 ian  staff     20 Sep 14 21:29 iplist.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ian  staff  55856 Sep 14 21:42 t.out
```

It can be a bad idea if you're going to use those commands as part of a pipeline, so perhaps sending the "reminder" to stderr would work to keep them separated?

```
$alias lsl='echo ls -l >&2 ; ls -l'
```

Comment: Also, seems like a duplicate of another question with similar answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823239/how-to-echo-os-x-bash-alias-command-to-terminal-after-calling-it-like-cmd?rq=1